# Why do I get InvalidCastException with two generics types casted as one?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Why do I get an `InvalidCastException` with the following code?

```
public interface ICommandContext<out TAssociatedObject> : ICommandContext<object, TAssociatedObject> { }

public interface ICommandContext<TParameter, out TAssociatedObject> : ICommandContext
{
    new TParameter Parameter { get; }
    new TAssociatedObject AssociatedObject { get; }
}

public interface ICommandContext
{
    object Parameter { get; }
    object AssociatedObject { get; }
    IMenuItem Menu { get; }
}

public class CommandHandlerContext<TParameter, TAssociatedObject> :
    ICommandContext<TParameter, TAssociatedObject>
{
    public CommandHandlerContext() { }

    public CommandHandlerContext(TParameter parameter, TAssociatedObject associatedObject, IMenuItem menu)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
        AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
        Menu = menu;
    }

    public TParameter Parameter { get; set; }
    public TAssociatedObject AssociatedObject { get; set; }
    public IMenuItem Menu { get; set; }

    object ICommandContext.Parameter => Parameter;
    object ICommandContext.AssociatedObject => AssociatedObject;
}

static class Testing
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var context = new CommandHandlerContext<object, IShell>();
        var casted = (ICommandContext<object, IShell>)context;
        var casted2 = (ICommandContext<IShell>)casted;
    }
}
```

The line `var casted2 = (ICommandContext<IShell>)casted;` throws an `InvalidCastException` and it's bugging me why is that.

I want to be able to define two generics arguments, but also only define the second one and have the first default to object.

Comment: The cast fails because `context` is not a `ICommandContext<IShell>`, it is a base class of that. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099440/how-do-you-provide-a-default-type-for-generics

Comment: To use a simple example: A dog is a animal, but not every animal is a dog. `CommandHandlerContext` is the dog. `ICommandContext` is the animal. Also please make examples that are less cluttered. You could literally have made this with dog and animal. Rather then using interfaces and classes that have 2 generic parameters.

Comment: You instantiate a new object that implements `CommandHandlerContext<object, IShell>`, and then try to cast it to a `ICommandContext<IShell>`. I'm genuinely curious why you think it *should* work?

Answer (score 2):

If we simplify the names a little:

```
A = ICommandContext<out TAssociatedObject>
B = ICommandContext<TParameter, out TAssociatedObject>
C = ICommandContext
```

Then the interfaces look like:

```
interface A : B { }
interface B : C { }
interface C { }
```

And the code looks like:

```
var x = new B();
var y = (C) x;
var z = (A) x;  // <-- throws an InvalidCastException
```

Note that in our interface definitions, `B` does not implement `A`. Therefore trying to cast `x` (which is a `B`) to an `A`, will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: `B does not implement A`, yeah I saw that and tried to `public class CommandHandlerContext<TParameter, TAssociatedObject> :
        ICommandContext<TParameter, TAssociatedObject>, ICommandContext<TAssociatedObject>` and that cannot be done either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316898/why-does-this-result-in-cs0695

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason is pretty simple. `CommandHandlerContext` implements `ICommandContext<TParameter, TAssociatedObject>`, not `ICommandContext<out TAssociatedObject>`.

I'm not sure the reason you need this, but wouldn't it make more sense just to cast to `ICommandContext` instead of `ICommandContext<IShell>`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep the classes from being piontlessly complex, I make the simple Animal/Dog examples.

```
class Animal{

}

class Dog : Animal {

}

var ItLives = new Animal();
Dog someDog = (Dog)ItLives;
```

That this does not work is clear. No amount of mad science will allow this cast to work. Note that it is also fundamentally different from:

```
var someDog = new Dog();
//The cast to animal is implicit
Animal someAnimal = someDog;
Dog = (Dog)someAnimal;
```

Just because for a while you Treat a dog as "just a Animal", does not mean it stops being a dog.

Also note that with Generics, casting is usually not as relevant. What usualy matters more is variance and covariance. It happens that you cast a `List[T]` to `IList[T]`, but usually those are implicit and they only change very little about the use.

Meanwhile it is more likely that you will variance (is that term?) a List[Dog] to a List[Animal] or vice versa. One of the directions is variance, one covariance. I just can never keep straight wich is wich.