# How to set a default type for T in a static generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I am working with my own custom stacks class, and I am trying to create a generic method for creating a new stack(a generic object). I work a lot with stacks that are type int, and only occasionally need other types. Can I set the defult Type of T to int?

Here is the method:

```cs
public static Stack<T> newStack<T>(int length)
{
    Stack<T> s = new Stack<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("print num");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
        s.Push(value);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I want to use the method like this:

```
newStack(5);//defult int type
```

and for any other type

```
newStack<string>(5)
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: There's [a few old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099440/how-do-you-provide-a-default-type-for-generics) that say that you can't, but I don't know if things have changed. The suggestion there is to make another method without the generic parameter that just calls the int verion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't specify a default type for T however you can simply overload the `newStack` method to get the behaviour you want.  The overloaded method will automatically create a new stack of type `int`.

Your code would look something like this:

```
public static Stack<T> newStack<T>(int length)
{
    Stack<T> s = new Stack<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("print num");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
        s.Push(value);
    }
    return s;
}

public static Stack<int> newStack(int length)
{
    // Call our original new stack method but pass
    // integer as the type T
    return newStack<int>(length);
}
```

Now you can call the second method if you just want to create a new stack of type integer like this:

```
newStack(5);
```

Otherwise you can create stacks of other types with:

```
newStack<string>(5);
```

Comment: Great answer. You answered first so I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a method newStack without the generics:

```
 public static Stack<int> newStack(int length) => newStack<int>(length);
```

The compiler is smart enough to select the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't, but you could use a, non-generic overload:

```
public static Stack<int> newStack(int length)
{
    return newStack<int>(length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either bear with the generic formalism and use the `int` type when you need it:

```cs
Stack<int> myStack = newStack<int>(5);
```

but if you really want to, you can define another method without the type parameter that calls the generic version:

```cs
public static Stack<int> newStack(int length)
{
    return newStack<int>(length);
}
```

```cs
Stack<int> myStack = newStack(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use overloading.

```
public static Stack<int> newStack(int length)
{
     return newStack<int>(length);
}
```