# How to pass a method with optional parameters as an argument?

Tags: c#, delegates, optional-parameters

Say, we have `ClassA` with method `Foo` containing an optional parameter. So, we can use it as shown in method `DoFoo`.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA() { }

    public void Foo(bool flag = true)
    {
    }

    public void DoFoo()
    {
        Foo(); // == Foo(true);
    }
}
```

Once I needed to pass it to another class `ClassB`. First I tried to pass it as `Action`, but the signature surely didn't match. Then I passed it as `Action<string>`, the signature matched, but the parameter in `ClassB` was no longer optional. But I did wanted to have it optional and came to an idea to declare a delegate. So, it worked.

```
public delegate void FooMethod(bool flag = true);

public class ClassB
{
    Action<bool> Foo1;
    FooMethod Foo2;

    public ClassB(Action<bool> _Foo1, FooMethod _Foo2)
    {
        Foo1 = _Foo1;
        Foo2 = _Foo2;
    }

    public void DoFoo()
    {
        Foo1(true);
        Foo2(); // == Foo2(true);
    }
```

So, the question is: can I somehow pass a method with an optional parameter as an argument without explicitly declaring a delegate and keep the optional quality of its parameters?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690482/parameter-actiont1-t2-t3-in-which-t3-can-be-optional

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman not a duplicate, the question is, whether there can be other work arounds..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the question is: can I somehow pass a method with an optional parameter as an argument without explicitly declaring a delegate and keep the optional quality of its parameters?

No. The "optionality" is part of the signature of the method, which the compiler needs to know at *at compile time* to provide the default value. If you're using a delegate type that *doesn't* have the optional parameter, what is the compiler meant to do when you try to call it without enough arguments?

The simplest approach is probably to wrap it:

```
CallMethod(() => Foo()); // Compiler will use default within the lambda.
...
public void Foo(bool x = true) { ... }

public void CallMethod(Action action) { ... }
```

Comment: Though this approach makes it impossible to pass not default parameters to `Foo`, I extremly like it, espesialy due to in my case, it's enough

Comment: As for my question, I thought I could be not aware of some C# way to define smth like `Action<bool = true,...>`...

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: "Something like" isn't detailed enough to know what you mean. You can declare your own delegate types of course, but if you want to declare a *generic* delegate type with an optional parameter of a generic type, the only default value would be default(T).