# Unit testing Dapper Update

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, extension-methods, dapper

```
Database.Setup(x => x.Update(It.IsAny<Subscription>()))
                    .Callback<object>(sub => SavedSubscription = sub as Subscription);
```

This line works with PetaPoco. Because of project requirements, had to switch to Dapper (and also had to add DapperExtensions in order to have CRUD methods) so now I am getting this error:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments

Any ideas how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Moq to mock methods that have optional parameters (as `Update` [does](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/blob/master/DapperExtensions/DapperExtensions.cs#L165)).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957537/how-do-i-moq-a-method-that-has-an-optional-argument-in-its-signature-without-exp) for more details, though you're stuck specifying all parameters to the `Update` method.

Note that this is a limitation inherent to the framework and not Moq; you can't pass a method with a default parameter to an `Expression`.  Jon Skeet gives a good demonstration why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249310/1698557).