# Can I define lambda default for some argument?

Tags: c#

For lambda like `Func<***>`, can I define some default value like the method(optional argument)?

Comment: looks like it's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249277/is-it-possible-to-use-optional-default-parameters-in-a-lambda-expression-in-c

Comment: Looks like Jon think it is impossible; however some dynamic language does permit.