# How to take an optional parameter for Action<T1,T2>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates, optional-parameters

I have a class that currently looks like this:

```
public Action<string> Callback { get; set; }

public void function(string, Action<string> callback =null)
{
   if (callback != null) this.Callback = callback;
   //do something
}
```

Now what I want is to take an optional parameter like:

```
public Action<optional, string> Callback { get; set; }
```

I tried:

```
public Action<int optional = 0, string> Callback { get; set; }
```

it does not work.

Is there any way to allow `Action<...>` take one optional parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690482/parameter-actiont1-t2-t3-in-which-t3-can-be-optional

Comment: It's unlikely this syntax exists. And how exactly would an optional parameter in the return value work?

Answer (score 12):

You can't do this with a `System.Action<T1, T2>`, but you could define your own delegate type like this:

```
delegate void CustomAction(string str, int optional = 0);
```

And then use it like this:

```
CustomAction action = (x, y) => Console.WriteLine(x, y);
action("optional = {0}");    // optional = 0
action("optional = {0}", 1); // optional = 1
```

Notice a few things about this, though.

1. Just like in normal methods, a required parameter cannot come after an optional parameter, so I had to reverse the order of the parameters here.
2. The default value is specified when you define the *delegate*, not where you declare an instance of the variable.
3. You could make this delegate generic, but most likely, you'd only be able to use `default(T2)` for the default value, like this:

   ```
   delegate void CustomAction<T1, T2>(T1 str, T2 optional = default(T2));
   CustomAction<string, int> action = (x, y) => Console.WriteLine(x, y);
   ```

Comment: There is a limitation with the generic approach, in that you always have to provide a Type for the optional argument, even when you don't need it. To make it truly optional, you'd have to declare multiple delegates for each use case, as such: 
`delegate void CustomAction<T1>(T1 first);`
`delegate void CustomAction<T1, T2>(T1 first, T2 second);`
A quick look at the framework implementation of Action<...> shows us  this is exactly how our friends at Microsoft do it.