# Event being called with wrong default parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, mono

I'm doing C# (with Unity3D / Mono Runtime 2.6.5) quite for a while now, but recently I encountered a very strange behaviour, when calling an event where a method with a boolean default parameter is attached to. 


When attaching it directly (Case 1), it somehow becomes `true`, even though the default value is `false`. While when attaching it via a lambda expression (Case 2), it is correctly set to `false`.


I really had expected it to become `false` in any case, where the param is not provided.


Attached you can find an example code of this strange behaviour:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public event Action SomeEvent;


    public void TriggerSomeEvent()
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
        {
            SomeEvent();
        }
    }
}


public class AnotherClass
{
    public AnotherClass(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        someClass.SomeEvent += AnotherMethod; // Case 1:  somehow "someParam" becomes true
        someClass.SomeEvent += () => AnotherMethod(); // Case 2: "someParam" becomes the expected false
    }


    void AnotherMethod(bool someParam = false)
    {
        // How can "someParam" in the first case (see above) become true?
        Debug.Log(someParam);
    }
}
```

Invoke the example by:

```
void OnGUI() 
{
    if(GUILayout.Button("test"))
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass();
        var anotherClass = new AnotherClass(someClass);

        someClass.TriggerSomeEvent();
    }
}
```

Output:

> true 
>   false

### Update

Like [Iain Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107580/iain-smith) pointed out the output is more of a random nature. So the first output does not always become `true`, it also turns to `false` from time to time.

Comment: Trying to compile this, getting errors in someClass.SomeEvent += AnotherMethod;  Can you please describe the environment you're in or double check your example?

Comment: I get a `No overload for 'AnotherMethod' matches delegate 'System.Action'` on your `someClass.SomeEvent += AnotherMethod;` line (case 1).

Comment: I double checked the example, it's working without any issues here. I'm doing this in Unity3D / Xamarin Studio / Mono Runtime 2.6.5 (shipped with unity 5.1.1). May be it is a Unity/Mono specific issue?

Comment: Just updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Did you create the event? Its obviously passing a boolean parameter of true.

Comment: Where does it "obviously passing a boolean parameter of true"? Could you explain this more in details?

Comment: Well i was asking if you created the event? Could you show the *actual* event definition? because by what you are showing it is clearly just passing a true parameter.

Comment: I cant see how it is 'clearly' passing true. This is really odd, I changed the type to int and it gives -1779033024, changed it to string and its gives System.Action. It might possibly be something to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7690501/1107580 "The runtime is not aware of optional parameters" but still i would have thought it would default to false.

Comment: Good finding! It really seems to be more of a random nature, as using an integer will provide a random number, each time. When I invoke it using my original bool param, and run it many times, it does also become `true` and `false` from time to time..