# Action variable signature for optional parameter

Tags: c#

```
public void Method(bool param1, bool param2 = false)
{

}
```

How to represent the above method as action variable?

```
Action<bool,bool> Action_Method;
```

Comment: [Parameter Action<T1, T2, T3> in which T3 can be optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690482/parameter-actiont1-t2-t3-in-which-t3-can-be-optional)

Comment: @JohnWoo:  Here i want to call Action_Method(true); - How can i do this?