# Overriding type parameters

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, hierarchy, parameterized

I'd like to implement the following classes with the following hierarchy:

```
public class DwellingPropertySetter
    extends AbstractPropertySetter<Dwelling>

public class HousePropertySetter
    extends DwellingPropertySetter<House>

public class SkyscrapperPropertySetter
    extends HousePropertySetter<Skyscrapper>
```

Unfortunately this code won't compile. A way to do it would be this:

```
public class DwellingPropertySetter<T extends Dwelling>
    extends AbstractPropertySetter<T>

public class HousePropertySetter<T extends House>
    extends DwellingPropertySetter<T>

public class SkyscrapperPropertySetter<T extends Skyscrapper>
    extends HousePropertySetter<T>
```

But for me those `extends` keywords are unnecessary.
Whenever I want to use a `SkyscrapperPropertySetter` I'd have to specify a type parameter. This is useless and would then look like `SkyscrapperPropertySetter<Skyscraper>`.

Do you know a way out for me? The only other way I know to realise my first hierarchy would be using interfaces and delegate methods.

Comment: Why do you want to use generics (like in your second example) when your first example seems to do what you need?

Comment: Because my first example won't compile. :-)

Comment: @NewTalk, here's a potentially stupid question: Why doesn't it compile?

Comment: @aioobe Because of _The type DwellingPropertySetter is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <E>_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have correctly recognized it is pointless to have something like ChickenArrayList<Chicken>, so you can either create something like

```
class ChickenArrayList extends ArrayList<Chicken>
```

OR, if you want to reuse some functionality in ChickenArrayList, you may have to make it abstract (and generic) and put another concrete, non-generic class on top of it:

```
class AbsChickenArrayList<T extends Chicken> extends ArrayList<T>
// and
class ChickenArrayList extends AbsChickenArrayList<Chicken>
class HenArrayList extends AbsChickenArrayList<Hen>
```

I know this is quite verbose, but this is the best you can do with this ~18 year old language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what is reasonable. If you have

```
public class DwellingPropertySetter
extends AbstractPropertySetter<Dwelling>
```

That means you have already made `DwellingPropertySetter` non-generic, all the method signatures will use `Dwelling`. If you say

```
public class DwellingPropertySetter<T extends Dwelling>
extends AbstractPropertySetter<T>
```

that means there can be various `DwellingPropertySetter`s -- and you really would like to have different ones, so I think this is what you really want to keep. Or is it your complaint that you want both a `DwellingPropertySetter` with no args, where `Dwelling` is assumed, AND a subclass extending `DwellingPropertySetter<T>` with a different `T`? That cannot be had with Java Generics.

Comment: Yes. I want to have a `DwellingPropertySetter` with no arguments and and a subclass extending `DwellingPropertySetter<T>` with a different `T`. Why isn't that technically possible? :-(

Comment: In Java Generics, but also in every other implementation of the same concept in other languages, a type either does or doesn't take type parameters. I've never seen a case where a type param would be optional with a default value. EDIT I googled a bit, C++ actually [does support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707780/is-there-a-reasonable-approach-to-default-type-parameters-in-c-sharp-generics) such a feature.

Comment: @NewTalk Nothing prevents you from writing `SkyscrapperPropertySetter sps = new SkyscrapperPropertySetter()` without the generics.

Comment: @assylias Only if he disables compiler warnings, otherwise the screen is going to crawl with yellow squiggles :)