# Can I make a generic optional, defaulting to a certain class?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

My question is related to [Is there a reasonable approach to "default" type parameters in C# Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707780/is-there-a-reasonable-approach-to-default-type-parameters-in-c-sharp-generics), but using an inner generic class that approach doesn't work.

Given code like this:

```
using System;

public class FooEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    // ... T properties and a constructor
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    public delegate void EventHandler<FooEventArgs>(object sender, FooEventArgs<T> e);
    public event EventHandler<FooEventArgs<T>> Changed
}
```

And with it being used like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Foo<int> foo1;
    public Foo<object> foo2;

    public User()
    {
        foo1 = new Foo<int>();
        foo2 = new Foo<object>();
        foo1.Changed += foo1_Changed;
        foo2.Changed += foo2_Changed;
    }

    protected void foo1_Changed(object sender, FooEventArgs<int> e) { ... }
    protected void foo2_Changed(object sender, FooEventArgs<object> e) { ... }
}
```

Well, I'd rather like it if I could have the generic optional, as there will be many cases where I don't know what type something will be coming in. (Data is coming from an external system which has its own variable types, which are then converted into .NET types, but I run into situations where, for example, one remote data type may turn into one of a couple of .NET types, or where it is of the "any" type—thus `object` would be the only real answer for that case.)

The solution which immediately occurred to me was subclassing (it was also the primary suggestion in the question linked to earlier):

```
public class Foo : Foo<object>
{
    public Foo(...) : base(...) { }
}

public class FooEventArgs : FooEventArgs<object>
{
    public Foo(...) : base(...) { }
}
```

I then want to use it like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Foo foo3;

    public User()
    {
        foo3 = new Foo();
        foo3.Changed += foo3_Changed;
    }

    protected void foo3_Changed(object sender, FooEventArgs e) { ... }
}
```

The problem is that it naturally won't work with `foo3_Changed` accepting `FooEventArgs`; it needs `FooEventArgs<object>`, as that's what the `Foo.Changed` event will get pass to it (as the value will come from `Foo<object>`).

```
Foo.cs(3,1415926): error CS0123: No overload for 'foo3_Changed' matches delegate 'FooLibrary.Foo<object>.EventHandler<FooLibrary.FooEventArgs<object>>'
```

Is there anything I can do about this, short of duplicating much of the class?

I did try one other thing: an implicit operator to convert from `FooEventArgs<object>` to `FooEventArgs`.

```
    public static implicit operator FooEventArgs(FooEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        return new FooEventArgs(...);
    }
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't seem to work, though I'm not quite clear on why:

```
EditBuffer.cs(13,37): error CS0553: 'FooLibrary.FooEventArgs.implicit operator FooLibrary.FooEventArgs(FooLibrary.FooEventArgs<object>)': user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed
```

So then, once again, is there anything I can do about this, or am I correct in thinking that it's Tough Luck and I'll just have to be content using `FooEventArgs<object>` (and then I guess I may as well just use `Foo<object>`)?

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/253)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't think there's much you can do about it, to be honest. You *could* make `Foo` doubly generic:

```
public class Foo<TData, TArgs> where TArgs : FooEventArgs<TData>
{
    public delegate void EventHandler<TArgs>(object sender, TArgs e);
    public event EventHandler<TArgs> Changed;
}
```

Then you could write:

```
public class Foo : Foo<object, FooEventArgs>
```

... but it's really making things very complicated for very little benefit.

I would also say that even though it's a bit more verbose to include the type argument, it does make it very clear - whereas inheritance can muddy the waters in various ways. I'd steer clear of class inheritance when you're not *really* trying to model behaviour specialization.

The reason your implicit conversion doesn't work has nothing to do with generics, by the way - as the error message states, you can't declare a conversion (implicit or explicit) which goes up or down the inheritance hierarchy. From the C# spec section 6.4.1:

> C# permits only certain user-defined conversions to be declared. In particular, it is not possible to redefine an already existing implicit or explicit conversion.

(See that section for more details.)

---

As a side note, I find it more common to use inheritance the *other* way round for generics, typically with interfaces:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    // Members which don't depend on the type parameter
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
{
    // Members which all use T
}
```

That way code can receive just an `IFoo` without worrying about the generics side of things if they don't need to know `T`.

Unfortunately, that doesn't help you in your specific case.

Comment: That's an interesting insight on the reverse manner of dealing with interface inheritance. But as you observe, that won't do in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Yes - I only brought it up as a side matter. I've edited the start of the answer with another idea, but it's not one I actually *like*.

Comment: No, I don't like it either... well then, explicit I think it is.

Comment: Great answer as always Jon.

Answer (score 52):

Another interesting thing I just found is that you can create generic classes with the same name but different signatures.

```
class Foo<T> { 

}

class Foo<T,T> { 

}
```

then you can call either one of them like follows:

```
new Foo<string>();
new Foo<int,double>();
new Foo<string,int>();
```

I just thought it was interesting that despite both classes having the same name they can co-exist because they have different signatures.

I guess this is how the Tuple class works

```cs
public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3... T8> 
{ 
...
```

Comment: Good answer. It's just similar to how overloaded methods work

Comment: @mojoblanco It is similar, at the class level.

Comment: Very useful answer that goes above and beyond this question.  Class overloading really helps to solve other issues.