# Why can't the compiler infer a generic parameter when there is a generic return value?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Consider the following function:

```
public void DoSomething<TSource>(TSource data)
{
   // ...
}
```

In C#, the compiler may implicitly infer `TSource`'s type by inspecting the method's argument:

```
DoSomething("Hello") // Works fine. DoSomething<string>("Hello") is called.
```

Why can't we do the same when there is a generic return value?

For instance:

```
public TResult DoSomething<TResult, TSource>(TSource data)
{
    // ...
}
```

`TResult` cannot be inferred (and I understand why), but the compiler can surely infer `TSource`'s type, can't it?.

However, this does not compile:

```
int result = DoSomething<int>("Hello"); // This should call DoSomething<int,string>("Hello")
```

Comment: That's just the way `C#` is. Either you give it all the generic arguments, or you give it none as long as they can be inferred. Can't go half-way. Not sure of the technical reason for this though.

Comment: You may check this one out:
[Is there a reasonable approach to “default” type parameters in C# Generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707780/is-there-a-reasonable-approach-to-default-type-parameters-in-c-sharp-generics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a matter of compiler - it's that C# requires that you either explicitly specify all the type arguments or let it infer all of them.

There is no middle ground using the syntax you've attempted, and I imagine it's because if you had a generic method like this:

```
public void DoSomething<T1, T2>(T1 data, T2 data)
{
    // ...
}
```

And you used it like this:

```
var obj1 = "Hello!";
var obj2 = "Hello?";
DoSomething<IEnumerable<char>>(obj1, obj2);
```

The last line could be shorthand for two equally valid things:

```
DoSomething<string, IEnumerable<char>>(obj1, obj2);
DoSomething<IEnumerable<char>, string>(obj1, obj2);
```

A different syntax (like `<string, ?>`) or additional inference rules would have to be put in place to make cases like this meaningful and non-ambiguous. I imagine the design team thought that it wasn't worth it.

---

Note that if you really want partial generic type inference, there is a common pattern of splitting the call into two calls, with a helper object to hold the information between the calls. This is essentially [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), applied to type parameters.

I'll present the pattern in a form that uses a public interface and an private implementation but if you're not concerned about that, you can skip the interface altogether.

```
public TResult DoSomething<TResult, TSource>(TSource data)
{
    // ...
}
```

Would become:

```
public IWrapper<TSource> DoSomething<TSource>(TSource data)
{
    return new WrapperImplementation<TSource>(data);
}
```

Where:

```
public interface IWrapper<T>
{
    TResult Apply<TResult>();
}

class WrapperImplementation<T> : IWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly T _source;

    public WrapperImplementation(T source)
    {
        _source = source;
    } 

    public TResult Apply<TResult>()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The usage is:

```
DoSomething("Hello").Apply<int>();
```