# Create a class with Optional Generic Type <T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's say we have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    void T SomeMethod()
    {
       // do work here
       return T;
    }
}
```

In the case above, the Type would need to be declared along with the class, but you *would not* need to specify the Type when calling `SomeMethod()`.

Or, you could also do this:

```
public class Repository
{    
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    void T SomeMethod<T>()
    {
       // do work here
       return T;
    }
}
```

In this case, the class would be created without a Type, but you *would* need to declare the Type when calling `SomeMethod()`.

Without a total duplication of all code, how would one create the same class so that the Type was optional when creating it? In other words, I'd like both of these to work upstream:

```
Repository<MyType> repo = new Repository<MyType>();
var something = repo.SomeMethod();
```

and

```
Repository repo = new Repository();
var something = repo.SomeMethod<MyType>();
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem... What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Could you just share the same internal implementation inside the two separate interfaces?

Comment: @Sweeper, nope. I asked exactly what I want to know.

Comment: @Oliver, that's the general idea I'm thinking too but I still can't see it in my head w/o a duplication of all code.

Comment: Repository can inherit from Repository<T> or the other way around, if you dont want duplicate code. You can also use a runtime `Type t = null` optional parameter.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707780/is-there-a-reasonable-approach-to-default-type-parameters-in-c-sharp-generics.

Comment: Side-note: if you're using an ORM (like Entity Framework) then you do not need to use the Generic Repository (Anti-)Pattern (or rather: you **should not** use the Generic Repository (Anti-)Pattern because the ORM *is* the repository already, e.g. `DbSet<T>`).

Comment: @Dia, using Dapper.

Comment: Is it your intention to create a generic repository for crud-like operations?  Dapper.Contrib.Extensions already does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is what you want to achieve, you could minimise duplication by wrapping the **generic method** implementation:

```
public class Repository
{
    public T SomeMethod<T>()
    {
        //Impl.
    }
}

public class Repository<T>
{
    private readonly Repository _base;

    public Repository()
    {
        _base = new Repository();
    }

    public T SomeMethod() => _base.SomeMethod<T>();
}
```

Where the **generic class** simply proxies through to the generic methods.

**EDIT**

Same concept as above, passing injected `connectionString` through to wrapped instance.

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public T SomeMethod<T>()
    {
        //Impl.
    }
}

public class Repository<T>
{
    private readonly Repository _base;

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _base = new Repository(connectionString);
    }

    public T SomeMethod() => _base.SomeMethod<T>();
}
```

Comment: I think this is probably as close as you're going to get.

Comment: So how does that constructor work?  Why isn't it simply `public Repository() { _base = new Repository(); }`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Cheers, I'd assumed some sort of DI, but I'll tidy it up for the sake of simplicity!  I've also removed the base type as it's not actually required.

Comment: I should have added the DI to the OP.  Hang on, I'll edit the OP. BRB.

Comment: @Oliver, DI added to OP

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I've updated to add an injected `connectionString` example.